# RXSwift - RxCollectionViewSectionedReloadDataSource - Drag & drop move (Reorder)

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I have used `RxCollectionViewSectionedReloadDataSource` to load my data into `UICollectionView`.

```
let dataSource = RxCollectionViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionModel<String, WorkGroup>>(
            configureCell: { (_, collectionView, indexPath, item) in
                guard let cell = collectionView
                        .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: WorkGroupCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? WorkGroupCell else {
                            return WorkGroupCell()
                        }
                cell.viewModel = item
                return cell
            }
        )
        
        viewModel.items.bind(to: tileCollectonView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource)).disposed(by: disposeBag)
 
        tileCollectonView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Using above code i can display the data. But i want to drag and drop(Reorder) the cell.

Please let me know how can i do that reorder using `RxSwift`.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, you need a state machine.

The logic involved is quite simple:

```
struct State<Item> {
    var items: [Item] = []
}

func state<Item>(initialState: State<Item>, itemMoved: Observable<ItemMovedEvent>) -> Observable<State<Item>> {
    itemMoved
        .scan(into: initialState) { (state, itemMoved) in
            state.items.move(from: itemMoved.sourceIndex.row, to: itemMoved.destinationIndex.row)
        }
        .startWith(initialState)
}

extension Array
{
    mutating func move(from oldIndex: Index, to newIndex: Index) {
        if oldIndex == newIndex { return }
        if abs(newIndex - oldIndex) == 1 { return self.swapAt(oldIndex, newIndex) }
        self.insert(self.remove(at: oldIndex), at: newIndex)
    }
}
```

The above uses the `ItemMovedEvent` provided by RxCocoa for table views. In order to create something like that for a collection view, you will need to wrap the `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` in a delegate proxy. An article on how to do that can be found here: [Convert a Swift Delegate to RxSwift Observables](https://danielt1263.medium.com/convert-a-swift-delegate-to-rxswift-observables-f52afe77f8d6)

Answer (score 0):

so I assume that you are using `RxDataSources`

after you set datasource variable, you need to set two more properties: `canMoveItemAtIndexPath`, `moveItem`

```swift
// in CollectionViewSectionedDataSource class
public typealias MoveItem = (CollectionViewSectionedDataSource<Section>, _ sourceIndexPath:IndexPath, _ destinationIndexPath:IndexPath) -> Void
public typealias CanMoveItemAtIndexPath = (CollectionViewSectionedDataSource<Section>, IndexPath) -> Bool
```

```swift
let dataSource = ...
dataSource.canMoveItemAtIndexPath = { dataSource, indexPath in
    return true
}
        
dataSource.moveItem = {dataSource, source, destination in
    ...
}
```

and use `UICollectionView` methods to start/update/end interaction.
in my case I added long press gesture to handle dragging

```swift
    //in viewDidLoad
    let startDragGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDragging))
    collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(startDragGesture)
    ...

    
    @objc func handleDragging(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView)) else { return }
            
            collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: indexPath)
        case .changed:
            collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: collectionView))
        case .ended:
            collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
```

then you can drag your cell

in `moveItem` closure, you should move actual data in your collection.